# Code Igniter : A Database Error Occurred SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload a website to the server. Code Igniter is framework that I 've used for this site and I'm using CI for the first time. While trying to upload the website to the server with following database setiings:

```
 $db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name',
    'hostname' => 'mysql:host=localhost',
    'username' => 'database_user',
    'password' => 'database_password',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
```

I've been getting errors as follows and I tried to search the net for solving my issues. I found some issues which were similar to mine but I can't figure out what I should be doing because most of the issues were for local servers. Please could someone help me out to solve it thanks.

```
A Database Error Occurred

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Filename: controllers/Home.php

Line Number: 9


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning  
Message: PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [mysql_old_password]
Filename: pdo/pdo_driver.php
Line Number: 133

Backtrace:
```

**Edit:**

[image: mysql info]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

or

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=codeigniter',
    'username' => 'codeigniter',
    'password' => 'codeigniter',
    'database' => 'codeigniter',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: doing 1st way it gave following error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in /home/name/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on line 136

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for database setting in database.php

```
$active_group = 'live';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['live']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['live']['username'] = 'user';
$db['live']['password'] = 'password';
$db['live']['database'] = 'database';
$db['live']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['live']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['live']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['live']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['live']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['live']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['live']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['live']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['live']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['live']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['live']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Set `$config["useDatabaseConfig"] = true;` in your config.php

I hope it will work for you.